# Retrieving the Video Records from Twilio Rest Api using c#

Tags: c#, json

My Requirement is  The video chats which is done through IOS phones or Android phones using Twilio Web RTC api , I have fetch that videos in my web page where user can play and download

Comment: I achieved it By the below code in ASP .Net MVC4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Index.cshtml

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
@model List<TwilioVideos.Controllers.HomeController.Recording>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
@*<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>*@
<h2>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Twilio Recorded Videos List</h2>
<br />
@if (Model != null)
{
    int i = 1;
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="    margin: 10px;" >
        <thead>

            <tr class="bg-success">
                <th>S.no</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>type</th>
                <th>videos</th>
                <th>status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if(@item.type=="video")
            {


            <tr class="bg-info">
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;@i</td>
                <td>@item.date_created</td>
                <td>@item.type</td>
                <td>

                    <video width="200" poster="/Images/mp4.jpg" controls>
                         <source src="@item.links.media" type="video/mp4">

                    </video>


                </td>
                <td>@item.status</td>
            </tr>
                i++;
        }
        }
    </table>
}


Home controller.cs

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Twilio.Clients;
using Twilio.Exceptions;
using Twilio.Http;
using Twilio.Jwt.AccessToken;
using Twilio.Rest.Video.V1.Room;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.IO;



namespace TwilioVideos.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public class GroupingSids
        {
            public string participant_sid { get; set; }
            public string room_sid { get; set; }
        }

        public class Links
        {
            public string media { get; set; }
        }

        public class Recording
        {
            public string status { get; set; }
            public GroupingSids grouping_sids { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string container_format { get; set; }
            public string account_sid { get; set; }
            public string room_sid { get; set; }
            public string codec { get; set; }
            public string source_sid { get; set; }
            public string sid { get; set; }
            public int duration { get; set; }
            public string date_created { get; set; }
            public string type { get; set; }
            public int size { get; set; }
            public Links links { get; set; }
        }

        public class Meta
        {
            public int page { get; set; }
            public int page_size { get; set; }
            public string first_page_url { get; set; }
            public object previous_page_url { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public object next_page_url { get; set; }
            public string key { get; set; }
        }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public List<Recording> recordings { get; set; }
            public Meta meta { get; set; }
        }











        private static Request BuildFetchRequest(FetchRoomRecordingOptions options, ITwilioRestClient client)
        {




             return new Request(
                Twilio.Http.HttpMethod.Get,
                Twilio.Rest.Domain.Video,
               "/v1/Recordings",
                client.Region,
               queryParams: options.GetParams()
            );

        }






        /*try */

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var options = new FetchRoomRecordingOptions(Roomsid, "");
            Twilio.TwilioClient.Init("SK0aXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "q7XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
            var client = Twilio.TwilioClient.GetRestClient();








            var response = client.Request(BuildFetchRequest(options, client));
            var o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(response.Content);
            List<Recording> cd = new List<Recording>();
            cd = o.recordings.ToList();
            return View(cd);
        }






    }
}
```